# Using DSACLS grant security permission to Users Object

Tags: powershell, cmd, active-directory

I'm trying to use `DSACLS` command to grant specific permission to a User object. `DSACLS` command will only available if you have AD-Snapin installed.

When I run this command on a User object, it will list all of its object security permissions:

`dsacls "CN=Aaron Ooi,OU=Users,OU=IT,DC=Domain"`

The permission that I want is from the list called:

`Allow BUILTIN\Windows Authorization Access Group
   SPECIAL ACCESS for tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal
          READ PROPERTY`

How do I use this command to apply the similar permission above to another User account? I cant seem to figure it out from the help menu.

If similar requirements could be done in `PowerShell` would be great as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Google everywhere, DSACLS could not do the work for special access permission. Then I looked for my answer in PowerShell and manage to find the solution:

You need to install Quest ActiveRoles for the PowerShell command:
http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx

After install, turn on the snap-in:

`Add-PSSnapin Quest.ActiveRoles.ADManagement`

Command to get the AD Object security permission:

`Get-QADPermission UserID -Inherited -SchemaDefault`

Command to set the AD Object security permission:

`Add-QADPermission UserID -Account "Windows Authorization Access Group" -Rights "ReadProperty" -Property "tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal" -ApplyTo "ThisObjectOnly"`

Issue resolved!